# Submit form w/ ajax not working

Tags: ajax, forms, post

I am trying to get my comments area to post without refreshing the page using the below code but It just refreshes anyway. I have tried putting return false; everywhere but nothing. Is there an obvious problem i cant see?

```
    $('#commentForm').keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        var songComment = $("#songComment").val();
        var username = $("#username").val();
        var comid = $("#comid").val();
        var dataString = 'songComment=' + songComment + '&username=' + username + '&comid=' + comid;
        if(dataString=='' || songComment=='' || username=='' || comid=='')
        {
            $('.success').fadeOut(200).hide();
            $('.error').fadeOut(200).show();
        }
        else
        {
            $.ajax
            ({
                type: "POST",
                url: "comment.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function(){
                    $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
                    $('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    };
});
```

Comment: This question can't really be answered without guesswork; could you place the relevant HTML and JS in a [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing in there which would cause the page to refresh. You're just submitting an AJAX request and you're not altering the window location at all nor telling it to refresh.

Do you have a submit button inside your comment form? If so, it's probably being activated when the user presses enter. You need to call `e.preventDefault()` to prevent the event passed to your handler function from taking its normal course of action. Specifically, you need to call that *within* your handling of *only* the enter key, i.e.:

```
$('#commentForm').keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // do stuff in response to enter key being pressed
    }
}
```

Otherwise, you'll stop *all* keystrokes from doing *anything!*

Of course, this might not help you if the submit button was activated *prior* to your event handler being called. Consider just using a regular button that *isn't* a submit button: use a [**button**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) or [**input**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) element with a type of **button**.

Comment: Forgot to mention my form gets submitted on enter press i.e.  $('#commentForm').keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {